# Solving inequality with logarithms.

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I was playing around and found this

$$x\log a\le a-1$$

Solve for $x$ in the above equation, where $a>0$

My attempt

$$\log a\le \frac ax-\frac1x$$
$$a\le \frac{\exp(a/x)}{\exp(1/x)}$$

But I don't really see any way to proceed

I'm especially interested in knowing if some value of $x$ always solves the inequality.

Comment: If you're solving for $x$, keep it on LHS and divide throughout by $\log a$. Note the sign of the inequality will change if $a<1$.

Comment: what kind of logarithm is it?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The natural

Comment: I'm especially interested in knowing if some value of $x$ always works.

Comment: $x=1$ always works...

Comment: @Macavity Can you prove that?

Comment: As space is constrained, posted the proof below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to show that $x=1$ always works.  So we need to show that
$$f(a)=(a-1)-\log a \ge 0, \quad \forall a> 0$$

$$f'(a) = 1-\frac1a = \begin{cases} < 0, && a < 1 \\ > 0, && a> 1  \end{cases}$$

So the function is decreasing for $a < 1$ and increasing for $a> 1$, hence it achieves its minimum when $a=1$, i.e. $f(1)=0$.  Hence $f(a) \ge 0$, so $x=1$ is always a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

You should discuss that $\log a> 0$,  $\log a<0$ and $\log a=0$ .

Comment: Nice, in particular for the $\log a = 0$ case +1.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on Macavity's excellent answer, here's a proof that $x = 1$ is 
the *only* value of $x$ that satisfies 
$x \log a \leq a - 1$ for all positive real values of $a.$

Let $x \log a \leq a - 1.$
For $a > 1,$ we have $\log a > 0,$ and therefore
$$x \leq \frac{a - 1}{\log a}.$$
Now consider what happens for values of $a$ greater than but very close to $1.$
We have
$$\lim_{a\to 1^+} \frac{a - 1}{\log a} = \lim_{a\to 1^+} \frac{1}{1/a} = 1.$$
If we set $x$ to any value greater than $1,$ we will then have
$x > \frac{a - 1}{\log a}$ and therefore $x \log a > a - 1$ for some values of $a.$

For $a < 1,$ we have $\log a < 0,$ and therefore
$$x \geq \frac{a - 1}{\log a}.$$
We have
$$\lim_{a\to 1^+} \frac{a - 1}{\log a} = \lim_{a\to 1^+} \frac{1}{1/a} = 1.$$
So if $x < 1$ we will then have
$x < \frac{a - 1}{\log a}$ and therefore $x \log a > a - 1$ for some values of $a.$
The value $x = 1$ is the only remaining value that satisfies
$x \log a \leq a - 1$ for all positive real values of $a.$

Answer (score 0):

we have to distinguish two cases
if $0<a<1$ then we have $x\geq \frac{a-1}{\log(a)}$ in the case that $a>1$ we have
$x\le \frac{a-1}{\log(a)}$ and for $a=1$ we have $0\le 0$